# Only Homepage not loading properly

Tags: plugins, themes, woocommerce-offtopic, errors, e-commerce

i am using estore demo theme for my eCommerce site. and yesterday i left it working fine,but today morning it homepage is messed up.don't know how.

You can check site here http://www.oriflamebeautyproducts.com/

And i am adding the error.log file from the cpanel..

http://www.oriflamebeautyproducts.com/errorlog.txt

please help me

Some Brief info about error

```
The WC_Cart::get_cart_url function is deprecated since version 2.5. Replace with wc_get_cart_url.

The WC_Cart::get_item_data function is deprecated since version 3.3. Replace with wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data.

The WC_Cart::get_remove_url function is deprecated since version 3.3. Replace with wc_get_cart_remove_url.
PHP Warning:  require(/home/oriflamebeautypr/public_html/wp-includes/post.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/oriflamebeautypr/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 166

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/oriflamebeautypr/public_html/wp-includes/post.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/oriflamebeautypr/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 166
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of different hings are going on according to your log:

1. The "deprecated" functions mean that you're using a theme that calls old functions. You need to update your theme to be compatible with the version of Woocommerce you are running. This doesn't break your site, but should be addressed.
2. The "warning" and "error" are due to WP not being able to reach its own required files. Best to open a support ticket with your host to address permission issues.

Comment: thanks for your help but now i got the problem, the problem is that i have choosed wrong product categories in widgets, because of that the page is not loading properly..